# Spring Controller double validation for @ModelAttribute object

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, spring-config

I have implemented controller with method:

```
public Page<EventDto> search(@ModelAttribute @Valid EventsCriteria criteria){...}
```

It works. `EventsCriteria` did not have special separate validator for itself, because it has inner annotation checkers like `@NotNull` `@NotEmpty`. Right now situation is changed and it's not enough to have only this validators. so I've added and registered correspond service to verify some sates.

I want service to verify additional composite cases and single validation like before. But my single inner annotation checkers like `@NotNull` `@NotEmpty` do not work any more.

Am I configured something incorrectly or it can't work in in same time(specified service and inner checkers)?

### My validator example (as it was asked in comments)

There are nothing special, if you know spring, so I missed this part like unimportant to concentrate your attention on my question.

```
@Component
public class EventsCriteriaValidator implements Validator {

    public static final String INVALID_RAGE_PARAMETERS_SPECIFIED = "Invalid rage parameters: please specify " +
            "'from' and 'to' or page 'size";

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.isAssignableFrom(EventsCriteria.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        EventsCriteria toValidate = (EventsCriteria) target;
        validateComplexRestriction(toValidate, errors);
    }

    private void validateComplexRestriction(EventsCriteria toValidate, Errors errors) {
        if (toValidate.isRangeEmpty() && toValidate.getSize() == 0) {
            errors.rejectValue(SIZE_FIELD, null, INVALID_RAGE_PARAMETERS_SPECIFIED);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `BindingResult bindingResult` add this in your controller method

Comment: `if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){return "errorr"}` check the condition here and return as you want as error message or page

Comment: Can you share your custom validation code?

Comment: @javaguy I'm not sure your request related on solution, but i've just added it any way :)

Answer (score 1):

Let assume that your EventsCriteria contains two fields so inside your validate method you can validate those field using : ValidationUtils (org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils)

```
 @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        EventsCriteria eventsCriteria= (EventsCriteria) target;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "field1", "eventsCriteria.field1.empty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "field2", "eventsCriteria.field2.empty");
    }
```

and in your **messages.properties**

```
eventsCriteria.field1.empty = Enter a valid value for field 1.
eventsCriteria.field2.empty = Enter a valid value for field 2.
```

and in your configuration class add this bean:

```
 @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      source.setBasename("messages");
      return source;
   }
```

Comment: Yea, that works, but it's workaround. I do not want implement behavior if same can be used by default, because of bad practice. but thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

If you want both custom and default validation you can use `addValidators` in 
`initBinder` to add your custom validations. This way default validations will not be deleted.

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private EventsCriteriaValidator validator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder)
    {
         binder.addValidators(validator);
    }

  public Page<EventDto> search(@ModelAttribute @Valid EventsCriteria   criteria, BindingResult result){

     if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // validation failed

     } else {
        //validation passed   
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: I need both validations buy default. I expected they'll used both because of `@Valid` marker.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `Validator` extend `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and then call `super.validate(target, errors)` in your validate method like this:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
   super.validate(target, errors);

   EventsCriteria toValidate = (EventsCriteria) target;
   validateComplexRestriction(toValidate, errors);
}
```

Comment: LocalValidatorFactoryBean handles annotation validation for you, wasn’t that what you need?